# chart.js coffeescript can't find variable

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, chart.js

I have this pie chart that displays correctly with the right data :

```
  # setup the pieChart
  if ($( "#pieChart" ).length)
    poll_labels = []
    poll_data = []
    poll_colors = []
    $('.option_text').each (i, obj) ->
      poll_labels.push($( obj ).text())
      return
    $('.nb_votes').each (i, obj) ->
      poll_data.push($( obj ).text())
      poll_colors.push('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16))
      return
    data =
      labels: poll_labels
      datasets: [ {
        data: poll_data
        backgroundColor: poll_colors
        hoverBackgroundColor: poll_colors
      } ]

    ctx = document.getElementById('pieChart')
    pollPieChart = new Chart(ctx,
      type: 'pie'
      data: data
      animation: animateRotate:true)

    $('#pieChart').on 'data:update', (event, data_id, data) ->
      $('.answer_option').each (i, obj) ->
        if($( obj ).attr('id') == ("option_" + data_id))
          this.pollPieChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = data
      this.pollPieChart.update()
```

However, the `data:update` event can't find the pollPieChart variable to update it?
it's not in `window.pollPieChart`, I can't find it under just `pollPieChart`. Did the variable "disapear" after the new ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pollPieChart` is a local variable, not a property on the event's `this` context.

Inside the `'data:update'` event listener, js automatically sets `this` to be the element on which the event occurred (`document.getElementById('')`).

Simply removing the `this.` from before `pollPieChart` inside the callback should fix it, as it is defined within the [current closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), not the global `window` object.

To place it on the global window (though it's not necessary here),use

```
window.pollPieChart = new Chart(ctx,
  type: 'pie'
  data: data
  animation: animateRotate:true)
```

Comment: hmm I could have sworn I tried just pollPieChart by itself before posting this. but it works now. Thank you!